# LP-Relaxation in Gurobipy

Tags: python, gurobi

I want to find an LP-relaxation solution to my problem by using Gurobi.py (a Python package for solving LP). I could do it by rewriting .lp file by changing all Integrality constraints to continuous. However, I do not want to write .lp file again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to do this, depending on your needs. Here are my recommended methods:

1. Easiest: create the relaxed copy by calling the [Model.relax()](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.5/refman/py_model_relax.html) method, which creates a copy of the model as the relaxed model.
2. Modify the model by iterating over all variables and set the [VType attribute](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.5/refman/vtype.html) to 'C' for continuous.
3. Most complex: write a callback function that calls [Model.cbGetNodeRel()](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.5/refman/py_model_cbgetnoderel.html) to get the relaxed solution at MIP nodes.

Comment: is there a way to retrieve the value of the objective function of the LP relaxation without solving the relaxation again? Because I think it is already solved in the root node when solving the MILP

Comment: @FarahMind if all you want is the objective value of the LP relaxation at the root, use the callback method (#3 above), for node 0.

Comment: Where to set the node to 0 here please: class LPValue : public GRBCallback
{
public:
    double lpval;

    void callback()
    {
        if (where == GRB_CB_MIPNODE)
        {
            int status = getIntInfo(GRB_CB_MIPNODE_STATUS);
            if (status == GRB_OPTIMAL)
            {
                lpval = getDoubleInfo(GRB_CB_MIPNODE_REL);
            }
        }
    }
};